# Django: Assign a model object as a ForeignKey before saving

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
    heading = models.ForeignKey(A)
    content = models.CharField()
```

When I tried to do the below I'm getting `IntegrityError: b.heading may not be null`

```
b = B()
a = A()

b.heading = a
b.heading.title = 'title'
b.content = 'content'

b.heading.save()
b.save()
```

Why is this happening? can't we work with objects this way?

Comment: You probably meant `b.save()` instead of `b.content.save()`?

Comment: yeah! its `b.save()` corrected the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually has to do with the order you do things.

When first assigning `a` to `b.heading`, the `A` object is not yet saved and doesn't have a primary key. Thus, on assignment, `b.heading_id` will remain `None`. `b.heading` doesn't know anything about `b`, so when saved, `b.heading_id` will remain `None`. When saving `b`, it expects `b.heading_id` to have a valid non-null value, which it obviously hasn't. Therefore, an `IntegrityError` is raised.

What you should do, is do the assignment after saving `a`:

```
b = B()
a = A()

a.title = 'title'
a.save()

b.heading = a
b.content = 'content'
b.save()
```

Comment: why the `heading_id` can't get updated this way? `b.heading` should also reference same object and `b.heading.save()` should also apply same changes in the attributes (I mean creating new pk value)

Comment: When you save `b.heading`, the model object itself gets a primary key value. However, with the implementation of foreign keys (more specifically the `ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor`), saving an already assigned foreign object does not change the foreign key value on the original model. `a is b.heading` will always return `True` as they are the same object, but that doesn't mean that `b.heading_id` will always point to the right value. You need an additional assignment to ensure that, that can be either `b.heading = a` after `a` is saved, or `b.heading_id = a.pk`.